# combobox in jtab

Tags: java, jcombobox, jtabbedpane

I'm trying to create a combobox in one tab while a button in another..
but the problem I'm facing is that i cant see the items of combobox..please help..
also tell me how to import image in another tab..

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
//import java.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.*;
class c_box extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Combo Box Demo");

        Panel p=new Panel();
        //  GridLayout gl=new GridLayout(1, 3, 30, 30);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800, 800);

        Vector comboBoxItems=new Vector();
        Vector comboBoxItems2=new Vector();
        Vector comboBoxItems3=new Vector();

        comboBoxItems.add("A");
        comboBoxItems.add("B");
        comboBoxItems.add("C");
        comboBoxItems.add("D");
        comboBoxItems.add("E");

        comboBoxItems2.add("1");
        comboBoxItems2.add("2");
        comboBoxItems2.add("3");
        comboBoxItems2.add("4");

        comboBoxItems3.add("1a");
        comboBoxItems3.add("2b");
        comboBoxItems3.add("3c");
        comboBoxItems3.add("4d");

        final DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(comboBoxItems);
        final DefaultComboBoxModel model2 = new DefaultComboBoxModel(comboBoxItems2);
        final DefaultComboBoxModel model3 = new DefaultComboBoxModel(comboBoxItems3);

        JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(model);
        JComboBox comboBox2 = new JComboBox(model2);
        JComboBox comboBox3 = new JComboBox(model3);

        p.add(comboBox,BorderLayout.WEST);
        p.add(comboBox2);
        p.add(comboBox3);

        JTabbedPane tab=new JTabbedPane();
        frame.add(tab, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JButton button = new JButton("Add new element in combo box");
        tab.add("tab1",p);
        tab.add("tab1",button);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but try changing one of the tabs names. Instead of using "tab1" for both tabs, try using "tab1" & "tab2" for example

Comment: it dosnt make any difference...its a title string..

Comment: i can see the comobox but its not active..plz hlp..

Comment: Works fine for me.  I did notice that you extend from `JFrame` but create another `JFrame` within the class though, not sure if has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add the JButton straightaway into the JTabbedPane you need to attach the JBuuton to JPanel and then add the JPanel to the JTabbedPane as follows.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JButton button = new JButton("Add new element in combo box");
panel.add( button);
tab.add("tab1",panel);
```